Leaving duplicated entries in a dataset at pretraining stage
I'm adopting a fine-tuning approach after having pretrained a deep learning model (transformer) on a source dataset (let's call it dataset A) and then fine-tuning it on a target dataset (B). Dataset A contains ~150,000 data points and some of them are duplicated entries (~30%). I want to clarify here that duplicates arise from the domain I'm working on, i.e. materials science where there can be multiple measurements of the same compound that are slightly different, for instance they come from different experimental conditions etc.
I need to save a small portion of A as a validation dataset at pretraining stage. The first thing that I've done has been processing and then discarding duplicated entries for this pretraining stage. However, I have noticed that by leaving these duplicates at pretraining, and then fine-tuning the model on dataset B, I obtain a remarkable improvement. Of course, I ensure that no data points are in common between dataset A and dataset B.
The thing is that, by leaving duplicates in pretraining stage, it happens that some data points will end up in both training and validation datasets and in principle, this might lead to bias or underestimation of the real error on truly unseen data. But apparently it is not the case for my specific task. What it is worth mentioning is also that although the inputs are duplicated, their targets might not be necessarily the same, as we are talking about measurements associated to chemical properties. Is there any reason why I could justify leaving duplicated entries and having them both in train and validation, at pretraining stage?

Hi, the duplicates here arise from the domain I'm working on, i.e. materials science where there can be multiple measurements of the same compound that are slightly different, for instance they come from different experimental conditions etc.
